# How to Change the ASCII value of a QR Code output

Tags: python, security, ascii, qr-code, zbar

I am building a robot using raspberry pi and open CV to read and display bar codes in real time. I currently have the output successfully decoding QR codes as expected.

My objective is to have the robot displaying a value "CCC" while an iphone QR Code scanner app would display "AAA", thus creating a 'secret decoding of the QR Code. I am unsure of exactly how to do this. Please see below the section of code which I belive to be relevant.

Thanks in Advance.

```py
while True:
        # grab the frame from the threaded video stream and resize it to
        # have a maximum width of 400 pixels
        frame = vs.read()
        frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=600) 

        # find the barcodes in the frame and decode each of the barcodes
        barcodes = pyzbar.decode(frame)

        # loop over the detected barcodes
        for barcode in barcodes:
                # extract the bounding box location of the barcode and draw
                # the bounding box surrounding the barcode on the image
                (x, y, w, h) = barcode.rect
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)

                # the barcode data is a bytes object so if we want to draw it
                # on our output image we need to convert it to a string first
                barcodeData = barcode.data.decode("ascii") 

                # draw the barcode data and barcode type on the image
                text = "{}".format(barcodeData)
                cv2.putText(frame, text, (x, y - 10),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to encode two different data into the same QR code in a way that an off-the-shelf decoder (such as the one on your phone) could decode it as "AAA" and another app "BBB".

You can of course encrypt the data in your QR code, but then it'd be gibberish for the off-the-shelf decoder.

**EDIT:** Of course you can do any transformations for the data you read, such as the ASCII code shift mentioned in comments:

```py
barcodeData = "".join(chr(ord(c) + 1) for c in barcodeData)
```

will turn "AAA" into "BBB".

Comment: is it at all possible to change the ascii value of my variable "barcodeData" by 1 or two places.

my original plan was to encrypt the data yet i believed this would be a much simpler solution if at all possible.